# Error occurred while mounting an NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, mount

Beforehand I'd like to thank your support to this question and hope you understand it.

I made 3 main partitions in my 500 GB hard drive to assign 40 GB for Windows 8.1, 40 GB for Ubuntu 14.04 and the last one called /windows, with 400 GB approximately, to share files between Windows and Ubuntu. It was working fine until I used Windows to rename the subfolders contained in /windows. Since then, when I start my PC and run Ubuntu it displays this:

```
An error occurred while mounting /windows.
Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

I'd like to share files like did before.

I'm new using Ubuntu and just know the basics. Sorry for my lack of english redaction.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=40ffb4ba-d9f4-4140-a532-66305bcac28e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c8b50f53-d9e1-4f75-81e6-d45a3d1d77dc /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=d8d19038-0e49-47e1-86d2-feca7c738dbf /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=70BEED26BEECE616 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=47071c68-4aff-46c4-a49e-c0eae38d8e58 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Use Windows to do a filesystem check on the shared partition. Then try with Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the fast boot option enabled in your windows OS. In one of my article, I explained little bit about the Reason and Solution for this problem. Please take a look and I hope this will be helpful.

Click on  [How to mount Ntfs Volume](http://www.gurjap.net/mount-partition-ntfs-file-system-ubuntu/)

Good Luck!

Comment: Your article was simple and accurate to solve my doubt. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Your welcome! Appreciated the comment :)